# How does Pixels Per Centimeter relate to zoom and pixelation of an image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, resolution

I'm working on something where an admin puts in a threshold for PPI of an image, for example 35. If the uploaded image has PPI of greater than 35 then return true or else return false.

So I'm finding out the PPI of an image using imageMagick:

```
identify -format "%x x %y" myimg.png
```

This gives me numbers, for example, 5.51 PixelsPerCentimeter and I convert them to PixelsPerInch by `5.51 * 2.35`

This all works fine. However, I am curious as to how the PPI relates to the zoom factor of an image.

**Questions**

Does a low resolution (say, 10 PPI) image mean it can't be zoomed in as much as a high resolution image can (say, 72 PPI)?

Well I'm sure a low resolution can be zoomed in at a high percentage but the image quality won't be as good i.e. it will be pixelated?

Is there a better metric that I should be looking at rather than PPI to determine whether an image is high resolution or low resolution.

Comment: Resolution is mostly meaningless in displayed images, it's the total size (width*height) that counts. Digital cameras for example will always report 72 no matter what their settings.

Comment: so should I be using the width and height of the image? what if a high resolution image has a small size?